# Strange issue in Xamarin, local images is not shown in IOS

Tags: ios, image, xamarin

I have added few images to my PCL project in Xamarin. 
Androids works fine with those images, but IOS can not display those images even though I am choosing BundleResource in BuildAction.

How it can be fixed? What can be a problem?

p.s. delete app from emulator, clean and rebuild does not work either

Answer (score 0):

You need to place images in both platform specific projects. While this guide is for Xamarin.Forms the advice works for non-forms applications.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Local_Images

Comment: You CAN but you don't have to. If you want to use only PCL message you can do this too